# Increase the value when a specific image is dropped

Tags: javascript

I can Drag and drop the images into the baskets and get the value for the object dropped into the basket. But  how to increase the value when a specific image is dropped into the Basket?

For example when I try to drag and drop the strawberry and the watermelon image the points increases by 10.Is there a way to increase the points by  30 by each image/meat item when chicken,turkey,Fish or lobster were dropped?

Here is a Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myscore=0;
function dragStart(ev) {
ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed='move';
ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.getAttribute('id'));
ev.dataTransfer.setDragImage(ev.target,0,0);
return true;
}
function dragEnter(ev) {
event.preventDefault();
return true;
}
function dragOver(ev) {
return false;
}
function dragDrop1(ev) {

var src = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(src));
ev.stopPropagation();
myscore=myscore-10;
document.getElementById('Score').innerHTML=myscore;
return false;
}
function dragDrop2(ev) {

var src = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(src));
ev.stopPropagation();
myscore=myscore+10;
document.getElementById('Score').innerHTML=myscore;
return false;
}

</script>
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesrod9000/e9w4w1sr/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an object for each image which is having the src image address and the score for that image only, and then you can use these images by passing all the objects in the array..

Hence, it will become easy for you to add more properties in the particular image object.

```
var strawberry ={
src:"address";
score:30
},

watermelon={
src:"address";
score:20
}
```